# doing to_dict() from a csv file not getting the dictionnary i want python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to map NACE code with sector activity from a csv file, i would like a dictionnary with this format :

```
  {'Nace Code': 'Nace Name',
  '7522': 'Defence activities',
  '9210': 'Motion picture and video activities',
  '9271': 'Gambling and betting activities', 
  ... }
```

I'm using the csv file dowload from https://opendata.eulerhermes.com/explore/dataset/nace-codeslabels-vs-trade-sectors/table/

My code is very basic :

```
dictio_nace = pd.read_csv('nace-codeslabels-vs-trade-sectors.csv', index_col=0, header=None,).to_dict()
dictio_nace
```

My output is :

```
{1: {'Nace Code': 'Nace Name',
  '7522': 'Defence activities',
  '9210': 'Motion picture and video activities',
  '9271': 'Gambling and betting activities',
```

I don't get why i'm getting this `{1:` at the beginning of my dictionnary and i don't know how to get ride of it.
Because of that i can't map with my database column.
Do you have an idea on how i could get ride of this `{1:` ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The `1` is the index. It's unclear how you want the structure. Would just `dictio_nace.values()` work?

Comment: dictio_nace.values() would work yes thank you

Comment: Should you read_csv using `index_col=None, header=0` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the index of the dataframe to the column you want as a dictionnary key should do the trick.

```
dictio_nace.set_index("Nace Code").to_dict()["Nace Name"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what i was looking for